# symfony api with vue form rendering?

Tags: symfony, vue.js, api-platform.com

I want to use Symfony + Api Platform. What Ive seen they render the forms using twig via the FormBuilder. Is there a way to use vue.js instead to render the form created with the formBuilder?

Comment: You have to make a choice to go with full RESTFUL implementation vs going web based hybrid implementation, there are lot of traits & factors which determines which architecture is best for your application. [Cloud Ways Vue Guide](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/symfony-vuejs-app/) shows how you can use both worlds in single app with encore, which is framework agnostic and lets you pick one for yourself. I'd suggest to go for restful app with separate frontend because api platform is designed to make that happen. Both are different technologies.

Answer (score 0):

FormBuilder is for server render pages. Vue.js is for SPA. I dont think that Api-Plaform uses FormBuilder. Maybe in admin or somewhere else, but not in core api service.

Answer is Yes. I think you should use SPA instead of server render pages.